# CakePHP 1.3 Custom 404 error for JavaScript or XML extension?

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I've set my router to parse the *js* and *xml* extensions, with the respective layouts for them.

But when there's an invalid */controller/action.js* or */controller/action.xml*, it will render the error404 page's HTML as plain text.

How do I force the 404 page to output a blank page for *.js* and *.xml*? Or, alternatively, have it do a redirect?